# Jersey 2.1 JsonMoxy configuration in web.xml

Tags: jersey, moxy

Anyone knows how how to configure jsonmoxy with web.xml, something like using sun(jersey 1.8)

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

It seems like many examples are running a standalone server and register a ContextResolver instance for the whole system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jersey will auto-discover MOXy as long as its on the classpath.

From Section 8.1.2.2 of https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.moxy

> As stated in the Section 4.1, “Auto-Discoverable Features” as well as
>   earlier in this chapter, MOXy media module is one of the modules where
>   you don't need to explicitly register it's Features (MoxyJsonFeature)
>   in your client/server Configurable as this feature is automatically
>   discovered and registered when you add jersey-media-moxy module to
>   your class-path.